# Specify a referential constraint with a constant

Tags: sql, entity-framework, constraints

I have one table that has a `Code` and a `Type` property. I have another table which has a `foo_id` property. The `foo_id` is a `Code` of `Type == foo` so when creating a constraint between these two tables I need to match `Code` to `foo_id` and `Type` to the constant `Foo`.

Is there a way to do this? I don't want to add an `Type` column to my second table that is going to have the same value for *every single row* because that seems like a waste.

```
Table 1                    Table 2
Code     <---------------  Foo_id                   Foo_id maps to Code
Type     <---"Foo"                                  But Table 2 doesn't have a property 
                                                    that maps to Type. But it should be 
                                                    constant
```

I'm creating an association between `Table 1` and `Table 2` in my `.edmx` file. When I click on that association and then click on the Referential Constraint, I can see `Code` and `Type` for the principle key, but I only have `foo_id` I can use for the Dependent Property. So I want to specify that the constraint for `Type` should be a constant.

There are, of course, other values for `Type` other than `Foo`, but `Table 2` in particular is only concerned with `Foo` types.

I can work around it by just doing something like:

```
var x = from i in Table2
        select new { someT2Prop = i.Table2Prop,
                     someT1Prop = (from r in Table1 where r.Code == i.Foo_id 
                                   && r.Type == "Foo" select r.Table1Prop).FirstOrDefault() };
```

But that's kind of messy. I'd like to just have a navigation property from `Table 2` to `Table 1`, so I could do something like this:

```
var x = from i in Table2
        select new { someT2Prop = i.Table2Prop,
                     someT1Prop = i.Table1.Table1Prop };
```

Comment: Can you provide a non `Foo`/`Bar` example? It may be easier to follow.

Comment: this is a standard join in relational databases... what exactly is your question?

Comment: or maybe you are staying there is more than one code which is type foo but you only want table 2's foo_id to allow that sub-set of codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question then:

Create a view:

```
SELECT Code 
FROM [Table 1]
WHERE Type = "Foo"
```

Then constrain on Code values from this view.

Comment: That's one idea. I was trying to avoid changing any existing tables or views because other applications rely on it, but adding another view would probably be okay. Although I'd prefer not to touch the database at all.